# How to compute the out-of-sample log-likelihood function?

Tags: time-series, garch, volatility-forecasting

I am doing some empirical work based on realized GARCH model, whose log likelihood function is given as
$$
l(r,x;\theta) = -n\log(2\pi) -\sum_{t=1}^n \left[\log(h_t) + \frac{r_t^2}{h_t} + \log\sigma_u^2 + \frac{u_t^2}{\sigma_u^2} \right]
$$
Here $h_t = var(r_t|\mathscr{F}_{t-1})$ is the conditional volatility and $u_t$ is a stochastic term with variance $\sigma_u^2$.

My question is how to compute the value of out-of-sample log likelihood funtion. For in-sample log likelihood function, we can simply plug in the estimated $h_t$, $\sigma_u^2$ and $u_t$. But normally how do people compute the one for out-of-sample testing?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a likelihood value for out-of-sample testing? I am trying to understand the question... Would a conditional likelihood make sense, where conditioning is on the parameters that were estimated in sample? You would use the estimated parameters from the in-sample estimation to obtain fitted values out of sample and use them together for the conditional out-of-sample likelihood. That's just a guess, as I do not quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RichardHardy That is exactly what he/she wants -  just use the estimated parameters to calculate the likelihood in the out-of-sample period. Hansen, Huang and Shek do that in this paper: http://public.econ.duke.edu/~get/browse/courses/201/spr12/DOWNLOADS/WorkingPapers_Now_Published/phs_realized_garch_10.pdf.